# is multipath the real cause of small-scale fading?

Tags: wireless, digital-communications

Since I was a student I've been told that small-scale fading is due to multipath propagation. 
With multipath you get constructive and destructive interference making the signal received power fade. Well that makes sense.

But here is my question: If you are in a completely static environment, say, locked on a room where **nothing moves**, you place your receiver at a point where you get constructive interference from multipath. Does your signal fade? If not, then small-scale fading is not due to multipath: is it due to **movement** and multipath. Movement between Tx or Rx or movement from the environment where the signal travels.

Since multipath is always there, it should be said that small-scale fading is due to movement and not due to multipath. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question, and explained it quite well. When people say *Multipath* they mean *Multipath Fading*. Without movement, we should call it interference or propagation or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *everything* in the room was perfectly stationary, and only a single frequency was transmitted and received, then its amplitude would be constant despite being affected by multipath. The only way you would know that multipath interference was occurring would be if the received amplitude was greater or less than expected.

However, unless the room is cooled down to absolute zero everything *will* be moving (even if only microscopically). The higher the frequency, the stiller you have to keep everything to create a stable interference pattern. Take away multipath and you need a much larger amount of movement to cause significant fading - but then it is a large-scale effect, not small-scale. So since movement is always there, and small-scale fading doesn't occur without multipath, how can we say that *movement* is the cause of small-scale fading?

Multipath can also cause fading effects even *without* movement. A practical device doesn't just send a single unchanging frequency and amplitude, but may spread its signal out over a wide bandwidth and/or hop between several different carrier frequencies. Different frequencies create different interference patterns which may be affected more or less by absorption/reflection of the room walls. The result is fading caused by multipath acting on the signal's frequency and modulation characteristics.

Comment: Even if everything in the room was perfectly stationary and a single, constant frequency wave was used, the amplitude received at the receiver would not be constant because multipath propagation would cause the transmitted signal to be dispersed in time and so the number of copies you are simultaneously receiving at the receiver will change with time.

Comment: @Bruce Abbot: I think that's an excellent answer. My only additional comment is, for a single carrier transmission at a "big" wavelength (at least some meters) you don't really need to cool down things to have a constant interference pattern in a room. I mean, the electron movement should not have any effect on the wave.